# How to make left menus height dynamic

Tags: css, master-pages

I am using Master pages with asp.net, I am noob in CSS, thus tried a lot of
properties after searching google and stackoverflow posts as well, but I cant
figure out how to over come this, the things are working fine except for the left
side menu, it should take all the height of the page dynamically, at the end I have
included a screenshot of Products page (buy.aspx) the product T2 and all other
products under it all left aligned with Categories while they should have
aligned under first product on the page, plz help

**Master Page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="E_Auction.Site" %>
<html>
<head runat="server">

<style type="text/css">
body 
{ 
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  background-color: Teal;
}
#header {
  padding: 1px;
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-right:5%;
  background-color: White;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#left {
  float:left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color:White;
    }
#center 
{
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: White;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  overflow:scroll;

}
    .style1
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .internal
    {
        text-decoration: none;
    }    
a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {color: blue;}
</style>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="header" style="background-image:url(Images/banner.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;">

<table style="height:27%;width:88%">
<tr colspan="2">
    <td style="text-align: right">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMyAccount" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/account.aspx" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="false">My Account</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp&nbsp
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBuy" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/buy.aspx" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="false">Buy</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp&nbsp
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSell" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/sell.aspx" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="false">Sell</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp&nbsp
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAboutUs" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/about.aspx" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="false">About Us</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp&nbsp
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkContactus" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/contact.aspx" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="false">Contact Us</asp:LinkButton>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">
    <br /><span class="style1"><strong>Search</strong></span>&nbsp<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Width="170px"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp<asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Go" Width="39px" Height="23px" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="bottom"><asp:SiteMapPath ID="smPath" runat="server" ForeColor="White"></asp:SiteMapPath></td>
</tr>
    </table>

</div>


<div id="left">

  <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="background-color:Silver;color:White;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">
                    Category
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="style1">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsCats">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <a href="buy.aspx?catid=<%# Eval("catid") %>" class="internal"><asp:Label ID="catitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("catitle") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCats" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EAuctionConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [catid], [catitle] FROM [Category]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </div>

<div id="center">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Following is content page**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="buy.aspx.cs" Inherits="E_Auction.buy" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>E-Auction::Buy Products</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    .topbanners
    {
        border: none;
    } 
    </style>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="prodid" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">


            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <span>No data to show.</span>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>


                <table width="50%">

                <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>
                <asp:Label ID="prodnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("prodname") %>' />
                </strong></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td rowspan="8"><img src='/Pimages/<%# Eval("prodimagename") %>' height="150px" width="150px" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <b></strong><asp:Label ID="capcategory" runat="server" Text="Category" /></b>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cat_title") %>' /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <asp:Label ID="capbidstartprice" runat="server" Text="Bid Start Price: " visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 1) ? true : false %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="bidstartpriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("bidstartprice") %>' visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 1) ? true : false %>' /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <asp:Label ID="captotalbids" runat="server" Text="Total Bids: " visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 1) ? true : false %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="totalbids" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalBids") %>' visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 1) ? true : false %>'/>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <asp:Label ID="capbidenddate" runat="server" Text="Bid Ends At: " visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 1) ? true : false %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="bidenddate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("bidenddate") %>' visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 1) ? true : false %>'/>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <asp:Label ID="capbuyprice" runat="server" Text="Buy Price: " visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 0) ? true : false %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="buyprice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("buyprice") %>' visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 0) ? true : false %>'/>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <asp:Label ID="captax" runat="server" Text="Tax: " visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 0) ? true : false %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="tax" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tax") %>' visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 0) ? true : false %>'/>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <asp:Label ID="captotalbuyprice" runat="server" Text="Total: " visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 0) ? true : false %>' />                
                <asp:Label ID="totalbuyprice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalBuyPrice") %>' visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 0) ? true : false %>'/>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <a href='buyform.aspx?id=<%# Eval("prodid") %>' class="internal">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='/Images/buy.png' runat="server" Visible='<%#(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 0) ? true : false%>' CssClass="topbanners"/>
                </a>
                <a href='bidform.aspx?id=<%# Eval("prodid") %>' class="internal">
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl='/Images/bid.png' runat="server" Visible='<%#(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 1) ? true : false%>' CssClass="topbanners"/>
                </a>
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr colspan="2">
                <td><b>Description</b><br /><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
                </tr>

</table>
<br />

            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                    <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </div>
                <div style="">
                      <p align="center">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                                </p>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>


        </asp:ListView>
        <br />


        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EAuctionConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [prodid], (Select catitle from Category where catid=p.catid) as cat_title,[prodname],[description],[pricetype],[buyprice],[tax],[bidstartprice],[bidenddate],[prodimagename],[isforsale],[addedon], [btnname], (Select count(prod) from Bid where prod=p.prodid) as TotalBids, (tax+buyprice) as TotalBuyPrice FROM Product p where isforsale=1 Order by addedon Desc">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <table runat="server" id="tblAll" width="70%" align="center">

</table>

    </asp:Content>
```

**Image of the product page:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put a height attribute of 100% on the left menu. But not only that you will need to put a height on the html, body and any other container element. If you set these all to 100% and that should do it.

```
height:100%;
```

Comment: Thanks it does a lot goood but not full, very hard to get the things
look similar on all resolutions. However, it did made me learn
so is the answer.